# AJAX refreshing part of a page why is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I spent two days now trying to write something which would allowed me to upload file through AJAX, now I am really close to that what I actually want to do, I can upload files through AJAX, but whole point of this idea was that I could upload files without refreshing page, now it refreshing my page and I don´t know how to solve it...
This is my current JS

```
 $('#profilovka').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var aFormData = new FormData();

            aFormData.append("subor", $('#subor').get(0).files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "upravit.php",
                processData: false,

                contentType: false,
                data: aFormData,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#nove').load(document.URL + ' #nove');

                }
            })
        }

    });
```

and my form look like this

```
<form class="profilovka" role="form" id="profilovka" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <tr>
        <td><label for="subor">Nahraj profilovku:</label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="subor" id="subor"></td>
        <td><button type="submit">Save</button</td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

that line off code  $('#nove').load(document.URL + ' #nove'); should do it, in different ajax methods it works, I thought that the mistake is in my form method and in that I have submit button there so I tried to make it like button and give a onclik="method()" to it and I made my JS look like function method () {
current JS code that you can see } but in that case the script doesnt do anything... is there any simple way to do it ? thanks for every help

Comment: Why not tag it with [tag:jquery]?

Comment: BTW, that's an invalid HTML code, as you cannot contain `<tr>` directly inside `<form>`.

Comment: what do you mean by tag it with jquery ? I am sorry I am warking with jquery/javascript for three or four days now so I had to make a lot of searching to write this code I currently have, and In six days I have a dedline when my page has to be done... and I still have some details which I need to do

Comment: What crazy thing are you talking? `:P` This is a jQuery question. So you should also add jQuery in the tags. Leave it. See my comment above. That's an invalid HTML first of all, might not work.

Comment: Why is that <tr> invalid ? i don´t think that this is the problem because it woudln´t be working at all if it was in that part or ? and I am trying to refresh div and the form is inside that div

Comment: Kindly check this out: [`<tr>` Usage Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Usage_context) - **Permitted parent elements:** `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` element. It also might be a cause.

Comment: So I found that I have to have a table inside a form, so I write to my form a table inside it, I think that is what you meant or ? but it still refreshing whole page

Comment: Rightly said. Refreshing? Check your console for errors. Should tell a clue.

Comment: In console there is write something like this : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function(anonymous function) @ prihlasenie.js:57

Comment: Looks like you are missing validate function?

Comment: okey so I add this in head of my document : <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>  now there is no error in console but my page is still being refreshed  :(

Comment: isn´t the problem with that submit button ?

Comment: What are you expecting would happen? You have a plain form with a plain submit button. If you want to intercept a form submit, you'd need a `onsubmit()`-handler.

Comment: Yes I thought that to problem is with that submit button but I didn´t know how to change it properly so now I add in ma form : onsubmit=" method();"   and my JS I made like function method()  { current code }  but its still being refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `return false;` to your submit handler so that the automatic submit of your form is prevented.

Comment: onsubmit="nahraj();return false;" I wrote something like this and page is not refreshing but my script doesn´t work now

Answer (score 0):

The submitHandler callback's first argument is event and you need to do [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

`submitHandler: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // And the rest of the code
}`

P.S: Please for the love of God don't use table for grid.

Comment: so I removed the line submitHandler: function (form) and I replaced it with what you wrote and rest of the code left there, but the page is still refreshing, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Seems fine in JSFeedle. I have no idea what plugin is providing the validate function so I replaced it with jQuery's built-in submit function. https://jsfiddle.net/0kbmq73m/

Comment: the script works but the page is still being refreshed, I am crazy about this already :( everytime I find something or someone post something here I am happy that this will work and than disappointed again... thanks for advice bytheway

Comment: Can you add a debugger inside the onSubmit callback and check if everything is working find.

Comment: you mean add a breakpoint in JS code ? or ? I am sorry this is my first page and it was like fast course I had to learn some way to work with css,html,php,javascript,ajax in like four weeks, and I am still missing many things

Comment: Yes that'll do it. For future reference you can type `debugger` inside your code and it would be recognized as a breakpoint.

Comment: and where can I look for debug results ?

Comment: It'll pause the code when it's reached. Add a breakpoint inside the submithandler at the first line. Check whether it's being executed or not. Maybe the problem is with your selector or you are not loading jquery.

Comment: I added few breakpoints there in JS and then working with page but all working as normal no change